# How to make DataGrid Row really fully selectable (clicking on non-cell area)

Tags: c#, wpf

The question might be a little misleading.

Here is a screenshot of a DataGrid that has some dummy values (code provided below)
[image: DGV]

Is there a way to make the white area not covered by a cell clickable? My intention: I want to have full row selection. This can be achieved by `SelectionUnit="FullRow"` which is fine but how can I make the white area implicitly select the entire row without **expanding available cells in width** and **avoiding code behind**

Here is the repro code:
Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="DGVRowSelectTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
   <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Names}" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow" >

   </DataGrid>
</Window>
```

Dummy Code behind of it (just sets the two entries up)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;

namespace DGVRowSelectTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private IList<KeyValuePair<string, string>> _names = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>{new KeyValuePair<string, string>("A1", "A2"),new KeyValuePair<string, string>("B1","B2")};
        public IList<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Names{get { return _names; }set { _names = value; }}

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have mentioned that you don't want to expand column width. This can be achieved with a hacky solution though `(by providing dummy column at last without any binding and setting width to *)`.

You have to set `AutoGenerateColumns` to `False` since you are explicitly specifying columns now.

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Names}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Key}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Value}"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Snapshot -

[image]

Comment: Brilliant. It breaks the auto-generated-columns feature, which is quite bad but at least this fixes my issue. Thanks!